# How do I unmount automatically and power off the device?

Tags: ubuntu, unmount

`mkdir /media/user/2; cd /media/user; mkdir 3 4 5 6 7 8`
`umount -R /media/` but folders are still persisting and crating a mess.
I did create fixed directories in `/media` but they still persist after unmounting, unlike Ubuntu which deletes them. It also power-off the device even when udisks is not installed. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From your example I see that you are in "/media/user" while you are trying to unmount "/media"
You can't unmount a folder which is used, or you have to force (-f) umount to do it.